# Can you efficiently add business day offsets to a datetime array & return the outer product?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, datetime

I have an array `A` of datetime objects of size n x 1 and an array `B` of integers of size m x 1. For each date in `A` I want to increment it by all business day increments specified in the array `B`.

Example:

```py
import numpy as np
from datetime import date
A = np.array([date(2021,6,1), date(2021,6,4)])
B = [0, 1, 2]
```

In this case, the required result is something like:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 2021-06-01 | 2021-06-02 | 2021-06-03 |
|  | 2021-06-04 | 2021-06-07 | 2021-06-08 |

That is, an array of size n x m. For row i, the values are `A[i]` + x business days for each x in `B`

The key requirement for the solution is that it be highly efficient (vectorised?). I will be performing this operation 100s of times with parameters m = 60,000 & n = 60. So at least O(10^8) datetime operations.

**What I've tried**:

I've found numpy's busday_offset method: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.busday_offset.html

Looks like you can feed it arrays & it will do some vectorised magic.

I have found that this works:

```py
np.busday_offset(datetime.date(2021,6,1), B)
```

But this does not:

```py
np.busday_offset(A, B)
```

I receive the error 'Iterator operand or requested dtype holds references, but the REFS_OK flag was not enabled'

What have I done wrong here? Are there better approaches to this problem?

Comment: A 'numpy array of `datetime` objects' doesn't exist. That's just a numpy array of `object`s. If you want numpy to be of any help for you speed-wise, you need a numpy array with `dtype` `np.datetime64`, which is *not* the same.

Comment: @orlp Thanks, this comment set me down the correct path. I have solved the problem & will post solution above.

Answer (score 0):

The `REFS_OK` flag error was caused because I had defined `A` as an array containing object types. If define the numpy array type correctly, and set the correct shape for the business day offset array then it works:

```py
A = np.array([date(2021,6,1), date(2021,6,4)], dtype='datetime64')
B = np.array([[0], [1], [2]])
np.busday_offset(A, B)
```

It yields a 3x2 matrix as required by the problem specification. The solution seems pretty quick too (quick-enough that it's not the bottleneck in my code anymore).

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/68200874/3) to the question [Can you efficiently add business day offsets to a datetime array & return the outer product?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68200874/can-you-efficiently-add-business-day-offsets-to-a-datetime-array-return-the-ou) by the OP [user2212859](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2212859/user2212859) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>